# Beautifulsoup python issue when looping through multiple pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to learn some basic webscraping using python beautiful soup. Intent for below code is to loop through 32 NFL team pages and return the Wins / Loses for each team. However whenever the code gets to the second iteration of the dataframe, I get the error returned below.

```
`import requests 
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

import pandas as pd

year = '2022'
df = pd.read_excel('NFL_Team_Names.xlsx')

for i, j in df.iterrows():
    url_insert = j[0].replace(' ', '-')  
    url = 'https://champsorchumps.us/team/nfl/' + url_insert + '/' + year
    print(url)
    req = Request(url , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    webpage = urlopen(req).read()
    soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")

    games = 18
    
    for x in range(1, games):

        insert = 'game_' + str(x)

        wl_count = 0
        row = soup.find('tr', id=''+insert)
        for elements in row.find_all('td'):   
            if(wl_count == 3):
                win_lose = elements.get_text().strip()
                print(j[0] + " " + insert + " " + win_lose[0])
            wl_count = wl_count + 1`
```

```
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

If I try each of the team names manually, code seems to work fine for the first loop. Am I missing something with using reqs/soup in loops that I need to be doing?

Essentially I want the code to loop through each url constructed from the teams file I'm using (simply an excel with each NFL team name) and print out the following for each team:

https://champsorchumps.us/team/nfl/Arizona-Cardinals/2022

Arizona Cardinals game_1 L

Arizona Cardinals game_2 W

Arizona Cardinals game_3 L

Arizona Cardinals game_4 W

Arizona Cardinals game_5 L

Arizona Cardinals game_6 L

Arizona Cardinals game_7 W

Arizona Cardinals game_8 L

Arizona Cardinals game_9 L

Arizona Cardinals game_10 W

Arizona Cardinals game_11 L

Arizona Cardinals game_12 L

Arizona Cardinals game_13 L

Arizona Cardinals game_14 L

Arizona Cardinals game_15 L

Arizona Cardinals game_16 L

Arizona Cardinals game_17 L

https://champsorchumps.us/team/nfl/Atlanta-Falcons/2022
etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are still using `pandas`, why not try [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) to fetch table data and process it to your needs:

```
import pandas as pd

for team in ['Arizona-Cardinals']:

    url = f'https://champsorchumps.us/team/nfl/{team}/2022'

    df = pd.read_html(url, header=0, skiprows=[1])[2].dropna(axis=1)
    df['Team'] = team
    df['W/L'] = df.Score.str.split(' ').str[0]
    print(df) # print, append to list, export, ...
```